# ansible-test UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3

Tags: python, ansible

### background:

Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
 Description:   Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
 Release:   18.04
 Codename:  bionic

```
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
SSH_CONNECTION=172.19.0.10 57690 172.19.0.67 22
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LANG=C.UTF-8
AMD_ENTRYPOINT=vs/server/remoteExtensionHostProcess
OLDPWD=/usr/lib/python2.7
COLORTERM=truecolor
ANSIBLE_HOME=/root/ansible
VIRTUAL_ENV=/root/ansible/venv
APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL=true
XDG_SESSION_ID=11
USER=root
PWD=/root/ansible
HOME=/root
```

python -V
Python 3.6.9

### problem description

i follow this 
tutorial https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#environment-setup
to run `ansible-test sanity -v --docker --python 2.7 my_test` my_test which module is mentioned in the above documentation. And i failed with following error message.

```
ansible-test sanity -v --docker --python 2.7  my_test
Run command: docker images quay.io/ansible/default-test-container:1.12 --format '{{json .}}'
Creating a payload archive containing 19605 files...
Created a 18417093 byte payload archive containing 19605 files in 2 seconds.
Run command: docker run --detach --volume /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --privileged=false --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --volume /var/run ...
Run command: docker exec -i 76e55178549fcd9f3ec3f735a88af91c356960c6e409d908897f657ef7c18ac4 dd of=/root/docker.sh bs=65536
Run command: docker exec 76e55178549fcd9f3ec3f735a88af91c356960c6e409d908897f657ef7c18ac4 /bin/bash /root/docker.sh
Run command: docker exec -i 76e55178549fcd9f3ec3f735a88af91c356960c6e409d908897f657ef7c18ac4 dd of=/root/ansible.tgz bs=65536
Run command: docker exec 76e55178549fcd9f3ec3f735a88af91c356960c6e409d908897f657ef7c18ac4 mkdir /root/ansible
Run command: docker exec 76e55178549fcd9f3ec3f735a88af91c356960c6e409d908897f657ef7c18ac4 tar oxzf /root/ansible.tgz -C /root/ansible
Run command: docker exec 76e55178549fcd9f3ec3f735a88af91c356960c6e409d908897f657ef7c18ac4 /usr/bin/env ANSIBLE_TEST_CONTENT_ROOT=/root/ansible LC ...
WARNING: Skipping tests disabled by default without --allow-disabled: docs-build, package-data
WARNING: Skipping sanity test 'action-plugin-docs' on unsupported Python 2.7.
No tests applicable.
WARNING: Skipping sanity test 'ansible-doc' on unsupported Python 2.7.No tests applicable.

WARNING: Skipping sanity test 'azure-requirements' on unsupported Python 2.7.
No tests applicable.
Run command: /usr/bin/python2.7 /root/ansible/test/lib/ansible_test/_data/yamlcheck.py
Running sanity test 'bin-symlinks'
Read 8765 sanity test ignore line(s) for Ansible from: test/sanity/ignore.txt
pre:changelogs/fragments/
path:test/integration/targets/ansible/ansible-testé.cfg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/ansible/bin/ansible-test", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "/root/ansible/bin/ansible-test", line 24, in main
    cli_main()
  File "/root/ansible/test/lib/ansible_test/_internal/cli.py", line 168, in main
    args.func(config)
  File "/root/ansible/test/lib/ansible_test/_internal/sanity/__init__.py", line 165, in command_sanity
    settings = test.load_processor(args)
  File "/root/ansible/test/lib/ansible_test/_internal/sanity/__init__.py", line 876, in load_processor
    return SanityIgnoreProcessor(args, self, None)
  File "/root/ansible/test/lib/ansible_test/_internal/sanity/__init__.py", line 450, in __init__
    self.parser = SanityIgnoreParser.load(args)
  File "/root/ansible/test/lib/ansible_test/_internal/sanity/__init__.py", line 428, in load
    SanityIgnoreParser.instance = SanityIgnoreParser(args)
  File "/root/ansible/test/lib/ansible_test/_internal/sanity/__init__.py", line 280, in __init__
    paths_by_test[test.name] = set(target.path for target in test.filter_targets(test_targets))
  File "/root/ansible/test/lib/ansible_test/_internal/sanity/__init__.py", line 760, in filter_targets
    target.path.startswith(pre)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 45: ordinal not in range(128)
```

### my progress:

i tried to locate the problem with simple print snippet code i added in the `/root/ansible/test/lib/ansible_test/_internal/sanity/__init__.py` i found it was `test/integration/targets/ansible/ansible-testé.cfg` this file with a character that is not in the ascii encoding.

after i dived into the ansible-test, i've found following code in `/Users/steveguan/code/Interest/ansible/test/lib/ansible_test/_internal/delegation.py`:

```
def generate_command(args, python_interpreter, ansible_bin_path, content_root, options, exclude, require):
    """
    :type args: EnvironmentConfig
    :type python_interpreter: str | None
    :type ansible_bin_path: str
    :type content_root: str
    :type options: dict[str, int]
    :type exclude: list[str]
    :type require: list[str]
    :rtype: list[str]
    """
    options['--color'] = 1

    cmd = [os.path.join(ansible_bin_path, 'ansible-test')]

    if python_interpreter:
        cmd = [python_interpreter] + cmd

    # Force the encoding used during delegation.
    # This is only needed because ansible-test relies on Python's file system encoding.
    # Environments that do not have the locale configured are thus unable to work with unicode file paths.
    # Examples include FreeBSD and some Linux containers.
    env_vars = dict(
        LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8',
        ANSIBLE_TEST_CONTENT_ROOT=content_root,
    )

    env_args = ['%s=%s' % (key, env_vars[key]) for key in sorted(env_vars)]

    cmd = ['/usr/bin/env'] + env_args + cmd

    cmd += list(filter_options(args, sys.argv[1:], options, exclude, require))
    cmd += ['--color', 'yes' if args.color else 'no']
```

it ought to decode the path with utf-8, but through the result it failed. any one have the same question?

Comment: Your error message is overflowing with "you are running this on unsupported Python 2.7" messages. Maybe you begin by using a supported Python version.

Comment: In official tutorial, python2.7 is showed as demo, so python2.7 must be supported

Comment: Okay, if you say so.

Comment: i aslo refer to an issue: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/68398